# Custom authentication strategy for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to write a custom authentication strategy for https://github.com/plataformatec/devise but there doesn't seem to be any docs. How's it done?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found this very helpful snippet in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/4ae0ce2b5f1003e8/9b9e9de48bc18673?lnk=gst&q=strategy#9b9e9de48bc18673) on the devise google group

initializers/some_initializer.rb:

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:custom_strategy_name) do 
  def valid? 
    # code here to check whether to try and authenticate using this strategy; 
    return true/false 
  end 

  def authenticate! 
    # code here for doing authentication; 
    # if successful, call  
    success!(resource) # where resource is the whatever you've authenticated, e.g. user;
    # if fail, call 
    fail!(message) # where message is the failure message 
  end 
end
```

add following to initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.warden do |manager| 
     manager.default_strategies.unshift :custom_strategy_name 
  end
```

Comment: thanks, very useful, I've used it for authenticating my old website's joomla users :-)

Comment: Very helpful answer, the link is broken though. Could you correct it?

Comment: I strongly recommend using [DatabaseAuthenticatable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb) as a template when implementing your own strategies, or else you may experience issues with rememberable not working, whose setup is done in its call to [validate](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L28-L45).