# Devise authentication gem: How I can configure for authentication with a MODEL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I need to customize DEVISE's configuration so the authentication can be done using my own model (which uses SAVON to ask a webservice) and not the database.

Comment: Check out this SO question and come back with what doesn't work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223083/custom-authentication-strategy-for-devise

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the device source.
This is the database_authentication module: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb

A nice solution i can think of is to make my own authentication module, like this:

```
  module Devise
    module Models
      module SavonAuthenticatable
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        # ...
      end
    end
  end
```

I didn't have time to spit out all the code of devise and there might be a better solution but this is just to get you started.