# How to generate an API Key and Secret in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

E.g. API_key: `4faa86aa5848207502000002` and API_secret `7375d7d1e89d3d602b184432fbcf3c09c7cb30676f19af9ac57d228be401`.

Should I use `SecureRandom`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ActiveSupport::SecureRandom would work for the actual generation**, but you should also consider a way to invalidate and reset the token on different events.

**Since you're using Devise, take a look at the [Token Auth Strategy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb).** You could **write a similar strategy with two tokens (API Key and API Secret, respectively).** You need to write both the strategy and the Model, but in both cases the Token Auth example gets you pretty far.

As a starting point (from the Token Auth example), your model should declare both required parameters.

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module APIKeyAuthenticatable
      ...
      def self.required_fields(klass)
        [:api_key, :api_secret]
      end

      def reset_keys
        self.api_key = self.class.api_key
        self.api_secret = self.class.api_secret
      end
```

You might also want to read [Custom authentication strategy for devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223083/custom-authentication-strategy-for-devise). If you're looking to provide a more full-featured API auth solution atop devise [devise_oauth2_providable](https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable) looks pretty good.

Comment: Both of these libraries don't look promising. I'm using Devise for user authentication.