# Combining 2 params to create the password when using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Rails 4 with Devise and I've got a situation where I need to log someone in where the password is made up of 2 separate input fields. After submitting, I need to combine the 2 inputs to form the password before the params get used to authenticate them.

I know the login details are correct because if I have a single password field it all works as expected.

As a test I've tried to submit a blank password and then intercept the params in the sessions controller by temporarily hard coding the correct password - e.g.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    params[:user][:password] = "ABCDE-12345"

    [... the rest of the standard devise sessions controller ... ]
  end
end
```

But that simply doesn't work. Something is happening before hitting this controller and any pointers on how I can intercept the submitted parameters would be appreciated. Code for the Devise controller is here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Do I need to write a custom Warden strategy perhaps?

Comment: why can't you modify your params with before_filter callback?

Comment: I've tried setting it in a before filter as well - same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've ended up with a custom Warden strategy (in config/initializers/xyz_authentication_strategy.rb):

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:xyz_authentication_strategy) do
  def valid?
    true
  end

  def authenticate!
    return fail! unless params[:user]
    user = User.find_by(login: params[:user][:login])
    return fail! unless user

    password = "#{params[:user][:input1]}#{params[:user][:input2]}"
    user.valid_password?(password) ? success!(user) : fail!
  end
end
```

and in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :xyz_authentication_strategy
end
```

Further reading on custom strategies: 
[Custom authentication strategy for devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223083/custom-authentication-strategy-for-devise)

Answer (score 1):

Your test may have failed because authentication may have happened earlier before the action is processed (or even before the `before_filter` callback). For example, an extension that calls `current_user` early in the execution chain. After you altered the `params`, `warden.authenticate!` is still called but the strategies aren't performed because they've been performed before (when the presumably `current_user` was called), that's how warden does things.

So I guess that leaves you with three options:

1. Find where the authentication is early performed and alter your params accordingly before it
2. Implement a custom strategy
3. Override [`params_auth_hash`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L92) method in an initializer