# How to add authentication before filter to a rails 3 apps with devise for user sign up and sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Given I'm on Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2 with a standard setup for devise to log a user in by name and password (e.g. similar to https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber ):

I need to add a layer that authenticates a posted username and password against an external service *before* creating a new user (sign up) *or* when a user signs in.

(FWIW, further down the road I plan on using the https://github.com/chicks/devise_aes_encryptable  strategy/gem to encrypt the sensitive password and, when logging in with a local password, decrypt the one for the remote service, authenticate, then continue with logging in, that is have two passwords, one encrypted one-way, the other reversible... don't ask why, anyway)

In lib/util/authenticate.rb I have an authentication class that returns a boolean against this service e.g.

```
Util::Authenticate.authenticate(username,password)
```

But, I can't figure out how to add a filter to authenticate against it on form post before authentication continues (for sign up or sign in).

**What I've tried:**

I haver a User model and I thought to put a

```
before_filter :authenticate_against_my_service, :only => [:create, :new]
```

in the UserController but that didn't work

So, I tried opening up the Devise Sessions controller, which didn't work, nor did subclassing it (e.g. in the README ),

```
class User::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # something
end

# in config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
```

nor subclassing the Devise Registrations controller (e.g. http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/ )and adding a before_filter (same as above).

```
# in app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end
end

# and in config/routes.rb 
root :to => "home#index"
#  replace "devise_for :users" with the below
devise_for :users,  :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
# other related code
devise_for :users do 
  get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
end
# resources :users, :only => :show MUST be below devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => :show
```

I think I have to do this in the controller because once the params get to the model, I won't have an unencrypted password to send to the external service.

I looked at some extensions for ideas such as https://raw.github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable/master/lib/devise_cas_authenticatable/strategy.rb e.g.

require 'devise/strategies/base'

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class CasAuthenticatable < Base
      # True if the mapping supports authenticate_with_cas_ticket.
      def valid?
        mapping.to.respond_to?(:authenticate_with_cas_ticket) && params[:ticket]
      end

      # Try to authenticate a user using the CAS ticket passed in params.
      # If the ticket is valid and the model's authenticate_with_cas_ticket method
      # returns a user, then return success.  If the ticket is invalid, then either
      # fail (if we're just returning from the CAS server, based on the referrer)
      # or attempt to redirect to the CAS server's login URL.
      def authenticate!
        ticket = read_ticket(params)
        if ticket
          if resource = mapping.to.authenticate_with_cas_ticket(ticket)
            # Store the ticket in the session for later usage
            if ::Devise.cas_enable_single_sign_out
              session['cas_last_valid_ticket'] = ticket.ticket
              session['cas_last_valid_ticket_store'] = true
            end

            success!(resource)
          elsif ticket.is_valid?
            username = ticket.respond_to?(:user) ? ticket.user : ticket.response.user
            redirect!(::Devise.cas_unregistered_url(request.url, mapping), :username => username)
            #fail!("The user #{ticket.response.user} is not registered with this site.  Please use a different account.")
          else
            fail!(:invalid)
          end
        else
          fail!(:invalid)
        end
      end
      protected

      def read_ticket(params)
        #snip
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:cas_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::CasAuthenticatable)
```

and read about devise/warden authentication strategies, e.g. https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies  but wonder if I need to actually create a new strategy (and if I can figure out how to do that)

**EDIT, POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:**

I like alno's suggestion and will try that, though it seems more like a monkeypatch than how devise/warden is meant to be used

```
module Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable
  alias_method :original_valid_password?, :valid_password?
  def valid_password?
    if Util::Authenticate.authenticate(username,password)
      original_valid_password?
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

alternatively, I've looked into adding a warden authentication strategy, but it's hard to figure out all the moving parts, e.g. from [Custom authentication strategy for devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223083/custom-authentication-strategy-for-devise)

initializers/authentication_strategy.rb: # this could be in initializers/devise.rb as well, no?

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:custom_external_authentication) do 
  def valid? 
    # code here to check whether to try and authenticate using this strategy; 
    return true # always use the strategy as only user's authenticate
  end 

  def authenticate! 
    # code here for doing authentication; if successful, call success! 
    # whatever you've authenticated, e.g. user; if fail, call fail! 
    if Util::Authenticate.authenticate(username, password)
      success!(true) # I don't think I want to return a user, as I'll let database authenticatable handle the rest of the authentication
      # I don't think I'm using success! correctly here: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies
      # success!(User.find(someid))
    else
      fail!("Username and password not valid for external service. Please ensure they are valid and try again.")
    end
  end 
end
```

add following to initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager| 
    manager.default_strategies.unshift :custom_external_authentication # will this check before or after database authentication? I want before, I think
  end 
end
```

OR from [How do I add a strategy to Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582537/how-do-i-add-a-strategy-to-devise)

```
class ExternalServiceStrategy
  def valid?
    true # always use this
  end

  def authenticate!
    # external boolean service call
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:database_authenticatable, ExternalServiceStrategy) # will this work before the db authentication?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see in [devise source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L39), you will find an `valid_password?` method, which accepts unencrypted password, so you may override it to authenticate versus some extenal service.

Something like:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  ExternalService.authenticate(email, password)
end
```

Comment: Look interesting, will try
module Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable
  alias_method :original_valid_password?, :valid_password?
  def valid_password?
    if Util::Authenticate.authenticate(username,password)
      original_valid_password?
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

You should be making your changes in the model layer, not in the controller. In fact I would advice you create a file in `/lib/whatever` that handles talking to the external service, and then modify your `User` model so that it checks the external service.

Comment: I apologize for not yet having added code examples.  Yes, I wrote a utility in lib/util/authenticate.rb that does the authentication e.g. Util::Authenticate.authenticate(username,password).  
Two problems with using the model as I see it 1) a validation would only apply on user creation or update, and would need access to the unencrypted password, (which it can't have, right?), and 2) I need to auth against the service on sign in of an existing user as well, to confirm the 3rd party auth is still valid (though ideally I could use the stored 3rd party password)

Comment: It is still absolutely the case that the right place for your code is in the model. If there are challenges associated with that then I'd suggest a new question.

Comment: Ok, I think I see how I could do it, the controller, which has access to the form data, can call a method on the model.  I could certainly use that approach, which I suppose is related to the modification of Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable as suggested by alno, as the model calls the macro :database_authenticatable